# Does Google/Firebase android SDKs use GRPC?

Tags: android, firebase, protocol-buffers, grpc

Recently I've been working on integrating a GRPC API in a **size sensitive** android app. The API only had a couple of Unary calls. I noticed that the resulting APK had `io.grpc` (613KB) & `io.opencensus` (178.9KB) which was further reduced to 387.2KB and 39.4KB respectively using Proguard. I noticed that Proguard was able to remove many streaming call related classes/methods from the APK. However, I noticed that the app already had `com.google.protobuf` package, which I suspect is from something like Firebase SDK.

If Firebase SDK imported `com.google.protobuf`, why didn't it need `io.grpc` for transport? Does it use something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The protobuf protocol is used by some Firebase SDKs as part of their internal communications. The first one that comes to mind is Firebase Analytics, but there are others too.

The Cloud Firestore SDK in Firebase uses grpc as part of its transport protocol. If you're not using Cloud Firestore then the grpc library will not be included as far as I know.

To ensure that unused methods are removed, be sure to use ProGuard as part of your release build.

Comment: Thanks for the response! We already use ProGuard but still have protobufs as part of the build, but not GRPC. So does that mean that some SDK internally uses protobufs objects but doesn't use GRPC? I know we use Crashlytics, MLkit and Firebase Analytics - Does any of these use GRPC? I'll check if we use Firestore SDK.

Comment: UPDATE: Just checked - we use firebase realtime-database currently, not Firestore.

Comment: Other services we use are firebase cloud messaging, performance monitoring, analytics, and remote config. None of these require GRPC?

Comment: Google Analytics for Firebase uses protobufs for encoding the data on its wire protocol.

Comment: Interesting, Thanks! I guess other services also do the same. (based on observations)